# Finding multiple supersets and subsets for values in a column with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to find supersets and subsets for values included in a column(here for letter column) from an excel file. The data looks like this:

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, D, E, F |
| 2 | B, C |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | D, B |
| 5 | B, D, A |
| 6 | X, Y, Z |
| 7 | X, Y |
| 8 | E, D |
| 7 | G |
| 8 | G |

For e.g.

- 'B', 'D,B', 'E,D', 'B,D,A' are subsets of 'A,B,D,E,F',
- 'B' is a subset of 'B,C',
- 'X,Y' is a subset of 'X,Y,Z',
- 'G' is a subset of 'G'.

and

- 'A,B,D,E,F', 'B,C', 'X,Y,Z' and 'G' are supersets.

I would like to show and store that relation in the separate excel files, first one includes (subsets and their supersets) second one includes supersets, First file:

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, D, E, F |
| 5 | B,D,A |
| 8 | E,D |
| 4 | D,B |
| 3 | B |
| 2 | B,C |
| 3 | B |
| 6 | X, Y, Z |
| 7 | X, Y |
| 7 | G |
| 8 | G |

Second file:

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, D, E, F |
| 2 | B,C |
| 6 | X, Y, Z |
| 7 | G |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be using `itertools.combinations` and check in every combination if all elements of the one item is in the other.

To find the supersets we take the `letter` column and convert it to a list of tuples. Then we create all possible combinations each with two elements of that column.
The line `a,b = ...` is to find the shorter element in that specific combination. `a` is always the shorter element.
If every letter of `a` is in `b` and `a` is in list `out`, then we remove it from the list because it is a subset of another element. At the end, `out` only contains the `supersets` of your data.
Then we only have to change the elements of the list to joined strings again and filter the `df` with that list to get your 2nd file (here called `df2`)

You need to be aware of how you split your strings in the beginning and also joining in the end. If there leading or trailing whitespaces in your data, you need to strip them, otherwise in the end the filter wouldn't match the rows.

**EDIT**
If you want to get rid of the duplicates at the end, you just need to add `.drop_duplicates(subset='letter')` at the end after filtering your df2. `subset` needs to be defined here, since both rows with `G` have a different value for `id`, so it wouldn't be considered as duplicate.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'letter': ['A, B, D, E, F','B, C','B','D, B','B, D, A','X, Y, Z','X, Y','E, D','G','G']})

lst = df['letter'].values.tolist()
lst = list(tuple(item.strip() for item in x.split(',')) for x in lst)
print(lst)
# [('A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'), ('B', 'C'), ('B',), ('D', 'B'), ('B', 'D', 'A'), ('X', 'Y', 'Z'), ('X', 'Y'), ('E', 'D')]

out = lst[:] #copy of lst

for tup1,tup2 in itertools.combinations(lst, 2):
    a, b = (tup1, tup2) if len(tup1) < len(tup2) else (tup2, tup1)
    # e.g for a,b : (('D','B'), ('B', 'D', 'A'))
    if all(elem in b for elem in a) and a in out:
        out.remove(a)

print(out)
# [('A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'), ('B', 'C'), ('X', 'Y', 'Z')]

filt = list(map(', '.join, out))
df2 = df.loc[df['letter'].isin(filt), :].drop_duplicates(subset='letter')
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   id         letter
0   1  A, B, D, E, F
1   2           B, C
5   6        X, Y, Z
8   9              G
```

**Additional Question**
get id's of sublists from superset:

You can create a mapping each row of `df` with `id` as key and the sublists as value. Then loop through `df2` and check if all elements of the sublist are in the supersets.

```
mapping = df.set_index('id')['letter'].str.split(', ').to_dict()
print(mapping)
```

```
{1: ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
 2: ['B', 'C'],
 3: ['B'],
 4: ['D', 'B'],
 5: ['B', 'D', 'A'],
 6: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
 7: ['X', 'Y'],
 8: ['E', 'D'],
 9: ['G'],
 10: ['G']}
```

Create new column:

```
#create helper function
def func(row):
    sublists = []
    for key,value in mapping.items():
        check = [val in row for val in value]
        if all(check):
            sublists.append(key)
    return sublists

# apply on each row of df2
df2['sublists'] = [func(row) for row in df2['letter']]
print(df2)
```

```
   id         letter         sublists
0   1  A, B, D, E, F  [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
1   2           B, C           [2, 3]
5   6        X, Y, Z           [6, 7]
8   9              G          [9, 10]
```

or as oneliner if you like to:

```
df2['sublists'] = [[key for key,value in mapping.items() if all(val in row for val in value)] for row in df2['letter']]
df2
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just have a more question. If I have same row value. For example as a 8. and 9. id with 'G' value. It wont have any superset so it will be its superset and I want to take just one of them in ooutput file. How can I make it?

Comment: please update your question with the new data, I'll have a look then. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @abcabc Thanks for editing, I updated my answer. If you like it, please consider voting/accepting it as the answer.

Comment: If I want to add a new column for id's of subsets for each superset, what should I do?

Comment: Thank you again. I just have tried to add something as a threshold value for being subset. For example, I want to add sub-ids that shared between 50 and 60 % score. and for all 100 scores I dont want add superset as subset to its sub-ids column. I just add 
'for tup1,tup2 in itertools.combinations(lst, 2):
    a, b = (tup1, tup2) if len(tup1) < len(tup2) else (tup2, tup1)
    if all(elem in b for elem in a) and a in out:
        out.remove(a)
    if 0.5<=len(a)/len(b)<0.6:
        out.append(b) '                 But it did not work. What should I do?